# Mongodb shard balancer stuck in state 0

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I've made sharding on one collection with 2 shards.
Mongodb version is **2.6.4**.
Everything looks ok but 100% of data is on one shard.

When I do:

```
use config
db.locks.find( { _id : "balancer" } ).pretty()
```

I get:

```
{
    "_id" : "balancer",
    "state" : 0,
    "who" : "ip-10-0-11-128:27018:1424099612:1804289383:Balancer:846930886",
    "ts" : ObjectId("553a1223e4d292075ec2a8a6"),
    "process" : "ip-10-0-11-128:27018:1424099612:1804289383",
    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-24T09:51:31.498Z"),
    "why" : "doing balance round"
}
```

So balancer is stuck in state 0. I have tried to restart it but it is still in state 0.

Also:

```
sh.isBalancerRunning()
> false
```

But:

```
sh.getBalancerState()
> true
```

Errors in my log file:

```
    2015-04-24T10:15:47.921+0000 [Balancer] scoped connection to 10.0.11.128:20000,10.0.11.159:20000,10.0.11.240:20000 not being returned to the pool
2015-04-24T10:15:47.921+0000 [Balancer] caught exception while doing balance: error checking clock skew of cluster 10.0.11.128:20000,10.0.11.159:20000,10.0.11.240:20000 :: caused by :: 13650 clock skew of the cluster 10.0.11.128:20000,10.0.11.159:20000,10.0.11.240:20000 is too far out of bounds to allow distributed locking.
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Looks like my servers are not in sync regarding time. There is 10 min delay in one of the shard servers and probably that's why it fails :/

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the code, it looks like we can tolerate about 30
seconds of skew between servers in the cluster.  On linux, we
recommend people use ntp to keep skew to a minimum (ntp usually keeps
it to within a second or two).  ntp is usually already installed on
most linux distros.

[Mongodb user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/SPi4Kqox16I)

using the following command to do an one time ntp synx

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```